# Is there a predefined #define or other way of knowing in source code it is being compiled for C++/CX Windows Runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, c++-cx

Visual Studio 2012 (and earlier versions) provide predefined #defines so that source code can be #ifdef ed appropriately, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

I would like to #ifdef some C++ code if it is being compiled (or not) for the Windows 8 Runtime (Component Extenstions for Runtime C++/CX) , i.e. with compiler switch /ZW, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561383.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx

Checking for C++ or CLR compilation is provided by __cplusplus and __cplusplus_cli (or __CLR_VER) respectively, but there doesn't seem to be a way of #ifdef ing for C++/CX /Zw Windows Runtime compilation!?

Does anyone know a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__cplusplus_winrt` macro is defined when C++/CX support is enabled (i.e., when compiling with /ZW).

Comment: a question: so is it possible to compile (with Visual C++) for WinRT without C++/CX?

Comment: @Adriano:  Yes.  Anything you can build using C++/CX you can also build using C++ without the C++/CX language extensions.  You can find a simple example component built without C++/CX (using the WRL library instead) attached to the article ["C++/CX Part 1 of n:  A Simple Class,"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/05/cxxcxpart01asimpleclass.aspx) which I published on the Visual C++ Team Blog a couple of weeks ago.